# pROC multiclass.roc - univariate case. How is AUC calculated in this instance?

Tags: proc-r-package

It is clear how the Hand and Till method works (from class probabilities) in the multivariate case and I have checked this against some code I wrote. I.e. I have used a 3 class problem and I get the same result as pROC. When I convert the 3 class problem into a 2 class problem (by merging 2 of the classes) I get the same results as pROC (still using multiclass.roc). However when I pass multiclass.roc the response with 3 classes, the 3 levels but only one class probabilities vector, I get another result.

I know this is handled differently; https://rdrr.io/cran/pROC/man/multiclass.html says "The multiclass.roc function can handle two types of datasets: uni- and multi-variate. In the univariate case, a single predictor vector is passed and all the combinations of responses are assessed.". However I haven't been able to find an explanation about what is happening here. Obviously it is something to do with the number of classes in the response (since this is the only other data) but I would be very interested to know what pROC is doing in such a case.

Here are my results (I wrote AUC_mc):

pROC: Class 3 univariate: 0.8494, Class 3 vs the rest (2 class): 0.9118
AUC_mc: Class 3 vs the rest (2 class): 0.9118

pROC: Class 1 univariate: 0.9721, Class 1 vs the rest (2 class): 0.9693
AUC_mc: Class 1 vs the rest (2 class): 0.9692823

```
#
# Here the probabilities for only 1 class are passed to pROC.   
# When there are 2 classes in the domain that's fine  
# When there are 3 classes in the domain then I get a different result
#
roc = multiclass.roc(test.df$response, probabilities[,n], levels=levels(test.df$response))
```

pROC: 3 class: 0.9568
AUC_mc: 3 class: 0.9567698

```
roc = multiclass.roc(test.df$response, probabilities[,], levels=levels(test.df$response))
```

Many thanks

Comment: Hi John, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you post the code that generates the results you see? You are more likely to get a useful response if you post code.

Answer (score 0):

In the univariate case, pROC tests all the 1 vs 1 comparisons. There is no 1 to the rest comparisons. So for 3 classes you have 3 roc curves: 1 vs 2; 1 vs 3; and 2 vs 3.

You can find [the source code in multiclass.R](https://github.com/xrobin/pROC/blob/master/R/multiclass.R#L85):

```
rocs <- utils::combn(levels, 2, function(X, response, predictor, percent, ...) {
    roc(response, predictor, levels=X, percent=percent, auc=FALSE, ci=FALSE, ...)
[...]
```

The [utils::combn](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/topics/combn) function generate all combinations of the elements of `levels` taken `2` at a time.

I will try to improve the documentation to reflect this better.